# Bash/Python: does `echo` command insert a newline when acting as input to another command?

Tags: python, bash

I have a simple python script `line_printer.py`:

```
import fileinput
i = 1
for line in fileinput.input():
    print 'Line', str(i), ':', line.strip()
    i+=1
```

I'm trying to understand how piping data in from the `echo` command to this script affects the result versus reading the data in from file.

Consider the following call and output:

```
$ echo -e "chicken\ncow\npig"
chicken
cow
pig
$
```

This to me looks like `echo` has appended an invisble `\n` after the "g" in pig.  So, how come when I call:

```
echo -e "chicken\ncow\npig" | python line_printer.py
```

I get:

```
Line 1 : chicken
Line 2 : dog
Line 3 : cow
```

as the output and not:

```
Line 1 : chicken
Line 2 : dog
Line 3 : cow
Line 4 :
```

At first I thought the behaviour of Python's `fileinput` module might be to discard the final line in a file if it is blank.  But when I try using the contents of a file `some_lines.txt`:

```
chicken
dog
cow
<blank line>
```

as the input:

```
python line_printer.py some_lines.txt
```

The output I get is:

```
Line 1 : chicken
Line 2 : dog
Line 3 : cow
Line 4 :
```

So why does `line_printer.py` give different results on the input depending on whether it originated from stdin versus originated from a file?  Best I can tell, both stdin (from `echo`) and the file (from `some_lines.txt`) finish with a `\n`, so I would either expect the output of both to include the `Line 4 :` or the output of neither to include it.

Comment: `some_lines.txt` ends with *two* `\n`'s: the one after `cow` and the empty line (which is a single `\n` by itself).

Answer (score 1):

This command will answer your question:

```
echo 'hi' | od -c
```

The reason for the trailing `\n` character is that stdout on a terminal by default uses line buffering - meaning it will only display output data that ends with the newline character.

Play around with the printf command:

```
printf "%s"  foo
printf "%s\n" anotherfoo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the bash source, bash-4.2/builtins/echo.def you can see that the builtin `echo` command always (line 113) outputs a final `\n` (line 194) unless the `-n` was specified (line 198) or output of `echo` is used as a string (line 166). You can test this by doing

```
echo `echo "Ho ho ho"` | od -c
```

You will see only one `\n` because the output of `echo "Ho ho ho"` is evaluated as a string in the expression `` echo `echo "Ho ho ho"` ``.

It doesn't seem to have any relation to the terminal setup.